# How to solve it with circle-dependency setter injection and @Lazy

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, circular-dependency, spring-bean

Recently, a circular-dependency error occurred in the project and I solved it this way, but I did not fully understand how this code works.
What exactly did @Lazy annotation do here?
Or how did it inject BeanB to form BeanA?

```
public class BeanA { 
private BeanB beanB; 

@Autowired 
public void setBeanB(BeanB beanB) { 
    this.beanB = beanB; 
}
```

}

```
public class BeanB { 
private BeanA beanA; 

@Autowired 
@Lazy 
public void setBeanA(BeanA beanA) { 
    this.beanA = beanA; 
}
```

}

Advance thanks.......

Comment: By default, Spring creates all singleton beans eagerly at the startup/bootstrapping of the application context. In your case beanA will not be initialized until you reference it somewhere in the code. So at startup, beanA is null. You can also look at here. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation